# Crystal report Data from multiple table?

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

I have 2 tables in program and I am trying to display data from these table to Crystal report.

- Table1: `student1` with columns (Name, RegID, Section, RollNo, sex, DOB, City, State)
- Table 2: `StudentCA` with columns (RegdID, LinuxCA, C#CA, SysCA, CryptoCA, DFCA, mode, total)

Code:

```
string query = "SELECT student1.Name, student1.Section, student1.RegID, studentCA.mode, studentCA.LinuxCA, studentCA.C#CA, studentCA.SysCA, studentCA.CryptoCA, studentCA.DFCA FROM studentCA CROSS JOIN student1 studentCA.RegdID = student1.RegID WHERE (student1.RegID = '" + txtRegdID.Text + "')";
objDA.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand(query, conn);

conn.Open();

objDA.SelectCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
conn.Close();

objDA.Fill(ds);
objCrystal.SetDataSource(ds);

crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = objCrystal;
crystalReportViewer1.Refresh();
```

but this code is generate an **DataSourceException** at run time.
I am using .Net framework 4.0,and Visual studio 2010.

**I am using .\sqlexpress for database.**

It give error like:

**Failed to load database information.**

**Error in File temp_eda0adfd-c6f7-45be-8440-fcbdcae02975 {289D4323-3A7B-45D7-80EA-345DD8BF7329}.rpt: Failed to load database information.**

Comment: Which RDBMS (SQLServer, Oracle, MySQL, etc) are you using this with?

Comment: Please share details of the exception

Answer (score 0):

Your immediate problem is probably caused by selecting `studentCA.C#CA` - the field name should probably be enclosed within the appropriate column-quoting characters for your RDBMS - for example, `studentCA.[C#CA]` if you are using MS SQLServer.

That said, a CROSS JOIN may not be the best way to join the two tables.